# Python XML eBay API Call

Tags: python, xml, ebay-api

I seem to be having issues with running calls on the eBay API. No matter what I throw at it, I keep getting the same output.

```
import requests

xml ="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetBestOffersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
 <<RequesterCredentials>
   <eBayAuthToken>'inserted actual token here'</eBayAuthToken>
 </RequesterCredentials>
</GetBestOffersRequest>
"""

output = requests.post("https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll", data = xml)

print(output.text)
```

The output that I always get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<GeteBayOfficialTimeResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<Timestamp>2020-12-23 05:20:07</Timestamp>
<Ack>Failure</Ack>
<Errors>
<ShortMessage>Unsupported API call.</ShortMessage>
<LongMessage>The API call "GeteBayOfficialTime" is invalid or not supported in this release.</LongMessage>
<ErrorCode>2</ErrorCode>
<SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
<ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
</Errors>
<Build>19110890</Build>
</GeteBayOfficialTimeResponse>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This seems to be some kind of Soap service. What happens when you use said credentials and call the url/operation from SoapUI? Perhaps your request is slightly off or contains typos?

Comment: It can be soap or xml. I'm somewhat versed in coding but extraordinarily new to APIs. So I have no idea whether this is setup correctly in terms of how a call is structured. I wasn't sure if I could be missing something blatantly obvious or not.

Comment: I think you mean "Json or XML"? Soap almost always is written in XML. REST Api's can be both but Json is more commonly used.  I don't know if this is the case for you, but I would personally go with the Ebay REST api if at all applicable/possible (https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/account/resources/methods). This uses the resources in the url and the HTTP verb's which you already use in requests (i.e. GET / POST/ etc.). My knowledge on the ebay api's and your situation are both pretty limited so please don't see this as an absolute answer, but rather more of a suggestion.